# Shared attributes in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have more models which have an address, some has just `address`, some has both `shipping_address` and `billing_address`. The scheme of the addresses is the same. In factory_girl I need to copy paste the address attribute definitions, but it would be great if some kind of macro could be used here.

I'd like to have something like that:

```
factory :organization do
  name          { Faker::Name.name }
  # this could define street, city, zip, ... with prefix shipping_address
  has_address :shipping_address
emnd
```

How to do it?

Comment: addresses can go to different column names? or its always `shipping_address` ?

Comment: Yes, it can go to column with different prefixes, so there is an address with fields street, city, zip, ... but it's prefixed by billing_address, shipping_address, etc.

Comment: Oh, the columns are prefixed. Then my answer is no good! If the addresses have the same schema, perhaps you can extract them into their own model (and db table) and use an association instead?

Comment: I can make use of your answer, I appreciated it. I had it association before, but that adds an additional complexity, which I do not want to pay. I try to avoid nesting, and use it only when there is a reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a trait could be a really good solution to your problem:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'active_model'

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :address
end

class Organization
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name, :address
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    name 'John Doe'
  end

  factory :organization do
    name 'Some corp'
  end

  trait :with_address do
    address '1234 Some road'
  end
end

p FactoryGirl.build(:person, :with_address)       #=> #<Person:0x007f8d220baca0 @name="John Doe", @address="1234 Some road">
p FactoryGirl.build(:organization, :with_address) #=> #<Organization:0x007fc9a1a30008 @name="Some corp", @address="1234 Some road">
```